# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I execute this code:

```
$db = new Database();
$statement = $db->prepare("SHOW TABLES LIKE :table");            
if(!$statement)
    throw New Exception($db->errorInfo()[2]);

foreach($tables as $table){
    $statement->execute(array(':table' => $table));
    if($statement->rowCount() == 0)
        echo 'Table ' . $table . ' doesn\'t exist';
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1 in something.php on line 4
```

The error isn't thrown when I put single quotes around `:table` like so: `$statement = $db->prepare("SHOW TABLES LIKE ':table'");` - but I thought you weren't supposed to put single quotes around parameters in prepared statements?
Also, I set this attribute to the database: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);`, so that `$statement` is false when wrong syntax used in the query, so I can throw an exception. The query can be executed when `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` is set to true.

My question is: how can I check for errors in my query when using `PDO` prepared statements? And why do I get the syntax error?

Comment: With named parameters, don't forget the colon (`:`): `$statement->execute(array(':table' => $table));`

Comment: @MarkBaker how come I never get an error for omitting the colon? I practically always forget it

Comment: @blackVeiledKilljoySkellington Because it works either way. You're supposed to use it, but PDO knows that all named placeholders start with a colon, so it adds it if you leave it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` option because native prepared statements can only use placeholders where expressions are allowed. `SHOW TABLES LIKE` requires a literal string, not an expression, so you can't use a native placeholder there. So put this before your code:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
```

Comment: Is there a way I can still throw an exception when there is a syntax error in the query then?

Comment: This doesn't change syntax checking.

Comment: setting `PDO::ATTR_EMULATES_PREPARES` to `true` does solve the error, but when I change my query to some random stuff (e.g `"SHOW BANANAS BLABLABLA LIKE :table"`), the exception isn't thrown

Comment: With the emulated prepares, you should get an error when you execute the query, not when you prepare it.

Comment: after executing the bogus query, `$db->errorInfo()` is empty

Comment: What happens if you use `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`?

Comment: thanks, that worked. Does setting the errormore to `EXCEPTION` mean that `if(!$statement) throw New ProgramException($db->errorInfo()[2]);` becomes useless?

Comment: Pretty much. Use `try/catch` instead.